# Authentication and Authorization in Cadence/Temporal

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

Does Cadence/Temporal provide any sort of Authentication and Authorization mechanism for accessing Cadence server/web-ui and for the communication between cadence/temporal server and Workflow/Activity Workers. I can't find any documentation around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporal has TLS support to secure communication between workers and the service. [Here is](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/learn-server-configuration#tls) the relevant documentation.

As of June of 2020 there is no other mechanisms to control access. We plan to add them during 2020.